# python `in` keyword as a function used in a filter

Tags: python, keyword

is it possible to use the python keyword `in` in a filter? I know that binary, unary, assignment operations are equivalent to a function call.

such as

```
''!=3
```

is the same as

```
''.__ne__(3)
```

is there an analogous thing for the `in` function?
I want to do something like this. ..

```
filter( list1.__in__, list2 )
```

I guess this can be accomplished with writing the in function... but i just want to know if it is already built in or not.

Answer (score 15):

```
filter( list1.__contains__, list2 )
```

is more cleanly written as:

```
[ v for v in list2 if v in list1 ]
```

and to show equivalence:

```
>>> list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [ v for v in list2 if v in list1 ]
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].__contains__(2)
True
>>> [1, 2, 3].__contains__(4)
False
```

And for what you want to do:

```
>>> list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> filter(list1.__contains__, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

In general you should use the functions from the `operator` module, in this case it would be `operator.contains`.

But there is much more efficient way to do this by using sets:

```
In [1]: list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

In [2]: list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [3]: list(set(list1) & set(list2))
Out[3]: [2, 4]
```

Note: The `&` operator is the intersection.

Comment: Using sets doesn't maintain the order of the elements.

Comment: This only works if the items in the lists are hashable.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension, as in Dan D.'s answer, is definitely the best way to do this.  In the more general case, though, where you want to use something like `in` or `not` in a function which takes another function as an argument, you can use a lambda function:

```
>>> list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> in_check = lambda item: item in list1
>>> filter(in_check, list2)
[2, 4]
```

Again, I present this just for your general knowledge; the best way to handle this specific case is definitely with a list comprehension, as in Dan D.'s answer.  More information on lambdas in Python is available [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk).

Comment: You should use functions from the `operator` module because they are much faster.

Comment: @ms4py: I would argue that in _most_ cases then enhanced readability and ease of use of `x in y` outweighs the benefit of using the operator module.  I would only use the `operator` module after I knew I needed the performance boost.